# Try - Except block waits for ctrl + c before catching exception (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, exception, try-except

I am testing some code and I wrote a try-except block to catch a RuntimeWarning that appears often, very simple stuff:

```
for i in range(sz):
    try:
        r[i],u[i],p[i],tr[i] = solver(S[i],trhoL,trhoR,tuL,tuR,tpL,tpR,gamma)
    except RuntimeWarning:
        exception_check = True
        exception_count += 1
        print("Skipping test....")
        break
```

When the exception occurs, the corresponding message appears on the screen:

```
/.../.../solver.py:71: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
dfR = (aR/(gamma*pR))*((p/pR)**(exp2-1))
```

However after that, the execution pauses and the except block is not executed immediately. I need to input <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> for it to resume and then the except block is executed.

Since these tests are done automatically I cannot press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> every time and, as far as I know, it should be asking for it either. Any suggestions??

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the result from `solver(S[i],trhoL,trhoR,tuL,tuR,tpL,tpR,gamma)`?

Comment: Is there some kind of test harness involved, like py.test, unittest?

Comment: @RolandasŠimkus solver() returns four values of type double

Comment: @renemilk No, there is no test harness involved, just simple debugging.